# Under what general conditions is the set $S := \left\{\int_{X}v(x)\pi(x)\,\mathrm{d}P(x) \mid \pi: X \to A\right\}$ closed?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, measure-theory, geometric-probability, set-valued-analysis

Let $X$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $A$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb R^k$. Let $P$ be a probability distribution on $X$ and $v$ be a $P$-measurable function from $X$ to $\mathbb R^{d \times k}$.

> **Assumption.** *$v$ is bounded on $X$, that is, there exists $R>0$ such that $\sup_{x \in X}\lVert v(x)\rVert_\text{op} \le R$.*

Consider the set $S \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ defined by

$$
S := \left\{\int_{X}v\pi\,\mathrm{d}P \mid \pi \in \Pi\right\},
$$

where $\Pi$ is the set of $P$-measurable functions from $X$ to $A$.

> **Question 1.** *Under what general conditions is $S$ a closed subset of $\mathbb R^d$ ?*

Perhaps even more generally,

> **Question 2.** *What is the closure $\overline S$ of $S$ in $\mathbb R^d$ ?*

---

### Partial solution when $P$ has countable support

Suppose $P = \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i\delta_{x_i}$, for some $x_1,x_2,\dotsc \in X$, and $0\le w_1,w_2,\dotsc$, with $\sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i = 1$. Let $M_i := w_iv(x_i) \in \mathbb R^{d \times k}$ for all $i$. Then, one computes
$$
\begin{split}
S = \left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty w_iv(x_i)\pi(x_i) \mid \pi \in \Pi\right\} &= \left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty M_i a_i \mid a_1,a_2,\ldots \in A\right\}\\
& = B_1 + B_2 + \ldots,
\end{split}
$$

where $B_i := \{M_i a \mid a \in A\}$. It is clear that each $B_i$ is compact in $\mathbb R^d$. Because $C := B_1 \times B_2 \times \dotsb$ is compact and the funciton $f:C \to S$ defined by $f(b_1,b_2,\dotsc) := \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i b_i$ is continuous, we deduce that $S$ is compact, and therefore closed.

Comment: What is $\pi v$? From what I see here, it seems that somehow I have to assume that each of the functions $\pi$, $v$, and $\pi v$ is $\mathbb R^d$-valued.

Comment: Sorry $v(x) \in R^{d \times k}$ is a matrix and $\pi(x) \in R^k$ is a vector. $v\pi(x) := v(x)\pi(x)$ is a matrix-vector product.

Comment: "the Minkowski sum of a finite number of closed subsets in a reflexive Banach space is closed" - this is not true even on the real line (consider the set $\mathbb{N}$ of positive integers and the set $\{-n-1/n|n\in \mathbb{N}\}$)

Comment: @FedorPetrov Thanks for the counterexample. I think I saw somehere that this is true with added restriction that at least one of the sets is compact.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Corollary 3.2 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/309873828_A_note_on_closedness_of_algebraic_sum_of_sets

Comment: @dohmatob That is about the sum of closed set and a compact set, not finitely many closed set. The counterexample above does not disappear if you add the compact set $\{0\}$.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker BTW, I was wondering if there is something similar for M-sum of countable collection of compact sets in the sense of https://mathoverflow.net/q/421287/78539.

Comment: @dohmatob It should work if the compact sets are uniformly bounded, otherwise there exists probably a counterexample. I'll take a closer look in a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that if $v$ is $P$-integrable then the answer is positive, and actually the set is compact.

Indeed, what you are looking for in this case is the compactness of the Aumann integral of the measurable multivalued integrably bounded function $v(\cdot)A$ with compact values in a finite-dimensional space.

In Aumann's original paper (Robert J. Aumann, *Integrals of set-valued functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **12** (1965), 1-12) the compactness of the integral is proved in this case for the Lebesgue measure (Theorem 4), hence the result follows if $P$ has no atoms (**Edit**: and is separable, see comments below).

I guess that the proof for general measure spaces with atoms is similar, especially since your argument shows that it holds if the measure space is purely atomic. Probably somebody has carried out the proof, though I do not know a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the nice insight (upvoted). Indeed, it seems Theorem 4 would establish the result for Lebesgue measure. How does one go from non-atomic to general measures on $R^d$ ? Is it via some kind of representation theorem for non-atomic measures (on $R^d$) ?

Comment: Also, by $v(\cdot)A$ you meant $v(\cdot )\Pi$, right ? That is, the collection of functions of the form $x \mapsto v(x)\pi(x)$ with $\pi \in \Pi$.

Comment: @dohmatob You can decompose  $X$ into a countable set on which $P$ is purely atomic and a set on which $P$ is nonatomic. You have a solution for both sets, the Minkowski sum will be again compact and give you your answer.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks for the insight. My issue is that i don't how to move from **Lebesgue** (the case treated in the reference paper) to  general **non-atomic** probability measures. But I might be missing something. (BTW, I started a thread on this issue here https://mathoverflow.net/q/421356/78539)

Comment: I'ved added a post here https://mathoverflow.net/a/421367/78539 trying to expand on my understanding of the above post (Martin Vath's answer).

Comment: By $v(\cdot)A$ I mean the multivalued function (which assumes values in the powerset of $\mathbb R^n$); the Aumann integral is defined as the set of integrals over all measurable selections of that multivalued function. Concerning going to Lebesgue measure: I had the theorem in mind that every atomless separable measure space is isomorphic to Lebesgue measure. I forgot to mention "separable". (One might still try to apply Maharam's results for the nonseparable case, but I am not sure whether this will lead to something.)

Comment: OK, thanks. I'ved added a post which captures my understanding of your solution (i.e providing low-level details) and your comments https://mathoverflow.net/a/421437/78539.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** *This would be too long of a comment, so posting here instead to get some input. This is an attempt to get a handle on user Martin Vath's answer. Thanks in advance.*

---

Let $P$ be probability distribution on a compact subset $X$ of $\mathbb R^n$, and let $F$ be a collection of $P$-measurable functions.
We are interested in the compactness of the set-valued integral
$$
S:=\int_X F\,dP = \left\{\int_X f\,dP \mid f \in F\right\}.
$$

Suppose $F$ is uniformly bounded, i.e., $b := \sup_{f \in F}\|f\|_\infty < \infty$, and for any
For any $t \in [0,b]$ and $f \in F$, define
$$
P_t(f) := P(\{x \in X \mid f(x)>t\}).
$$

By the [layer-cake representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_cake_representation), one can write

$$
S := \int_X F\,dP = \int_0^bP_t(F)\,dt,
$$
where $P_t(F) := \{P_t(f) \mid f \in F\}$.

> Thanks to Theorem 4 of Aumann 1965 (the paper cited by Martin Vath, for $S$ to be compact, it suffices that $P_t(F)$ be closed for (almost) any $t \in [0,b]$.

In my specific question (and taking $d=1$ for simplicity), $F$ is collection of functions of the form $x \mapsto v(x)\cdot \pi(x)$, where $v:X \mapsto \mathbb R^k$ is a bounded $P$-measurable function function and $\pi$ runs over $P$-measurable functions $X \mapsto A$, with $A$ being a fixed compact subset of $\mathbb R^k$.

Moreover, to ensure $F$ is uniformly bounded, it suffices to demand $v$ be bounded; we can then take $b = \mathrm{diam}(A)\cdot\sup_{x \in X}\|v(x)\|<\infty$.

> **Question.** *For such an $F$, is it true $P_t(F)$ is closed for (almost) any $t \in [0,b]$ ?*

### Partial solution when $P$ has countable support

Suppose $P = \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i \delta_{x_i}$, with $(x_i)_i \subseteq X$ and $(w_i)_i \in \ell^1(\mathbb R)$. Then, a direct computation gives
$$
\begin{split}
P_t(F) &= \left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i1_{v(x_i)\cdot \pi(x_i)  \,>\, t} \mid \pi \in \Pi\right\}\\
&=\left\{\sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i1_{v(x_i)\cdot a_i  \,>\, t} \mid (a_i)_i \subseteq A\right\}\\
& = \sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i u_i(A)\text{ (Minkowski sum)},
\end{split}
$$
where $u_i(a) := 1_{v(x_i)\cdot a \,>\, t} \in \{0,1\}$. Thus, we see that $P_t(F)$ is a subset of values for the subsums of $\sum_{i=1}^\infty w_i$, and so must be closed (since there are only countably many distinct values for these subsums). We thus recover the result established in the original question.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment to my reply, I had a direct application of the measure isomorphism theorem in mind (which requires separability). However, I think that simply the *proof* of the convexity result by Aumann requires only a non-atomaic measure space, that is *without loss of generality* you can assume in a non-atomic measure space that $A$ is convex, and then again Aumann's proof for compactness should directly hold. Alternatively, once you assume that $A$ is convex, you can apply some of many results which establish equality of the Aumann and the Debreu integral.

Comment: (continuing comment): Note that the Debreu integral is defined by means of approximation of the mutlivalued functions in the hyperspace of nonempty compact (convex?) sets with the Hausdorff metric, hence *by definition* is compact (and convex). All result establishing this equality are one sense or another based on the weak compactness in $L_1$ of the set of selections of an integrably bounded multivalued map with compact convex values. I am afraid that for this result convexity is crucial.

Comment: Thanks for the input. In fact in my original question $A$ was compact and **convex** (the unit probability simplex in $\mathbb R^k$). I diidn't know convexity would play in the problem, and so I suppressed it. Concerning the equality of the Aumann and Debreu integrals, is there are clear reference for this result ? (**N.B.:** I'm only learning all of this set-valued analysis here on the fly based on these interactions). Thanks.

Comment: I guess you were referring to something like Theorem 3.11 of this paper https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.36.3148&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer.** *This post is mostly to provide some low-level details for Martin Vath's answer and comments. Note that my previous post https://mathoverflow.net/a/421367/78539 didn't quite correspond to what Martin Vath intended, though it still ends up solving the problem for the special case of countably supported $P$.*

---

We shall work under the following assumption:

> **Asumption 1.** *For the function $v:X \to \mathbb R^{d\times k}$ in the question, $\|v\|:x \mapsto \|v(x)\|_{op}$ is $P$-integrable.*

### Method 1: Via Maraham's theorem

The **separable** probability measure space $(X,P)$ can be decomposed into the sum of an atomic part (i.e with countable support) and a non-atomic part (i.e containing no atoms) which is isomorphic to $L:=([0,1],\mathcal B([0,1]), dx)$, the standard Lebesgue space. The set $S$ in the question then decomposes as a Minkowski sum of isomorphic images of the versions $S$ corresponding to each part of this decomposition.

> Thus, we only need to study the compactness of $S$ in the case where the original probability space $(X,P)$ is atomic (done!) and the case where it is the standard Lebesgue space $L$.

Thus, let $(X,P) = L$, the standard Lebesgue measure space. Consider the set-valued map $F:X \to 2^{\mathbb R^d}$ defined by
$$
F(x) := v(x)\cdot A := \{v(x) a \mid a \in A\},
$$
Then, the set $\mathcal S$ in the original question can be written as the Aumann integral of $F$ over $X$, i.e
$$
S = \int_X F\,dP := \left\{\int_X f\,dP \,\,\big |\,\, f \in \mathfrak F\right\},
$$
where $\mathfrak F$ be the collection of all integrable functions $f:X \to \mathbb R$ such that $f(x) \in F(x)$ for all $x \in X$.

We observe the following:

- Since $A$ is closed (compact), $F(x):=v(x)A$ is closed (compact) for every $x \in X$.
- Since $A\subseteq \mathbb R^k$ is compact, it is clear that $F$ is integrably bounded by the function $h:X \to \mathbb R_+$ defined by $h(x):=\mathrm{diam}(A)\cdot\|v(x)\|_{op}$, meaning that $h$ is $P$-integrable and
  $$
  \|z\| \le h(x),\text{ for every }x \in X, \,z \in F(x).
  $$

> It then follows from Theorem 4 of Robert J. Aumann, Integrals of set-valued functions, J. Math. Anal. Appl. 12 (1965), 1-12) that $S$ is compact.

### Method 2: via Debreu-Aumann equivalence

> **Assumption 2.** *$A$ is convex.*

Under **Assumption 1** and **Assumption 2**, the compactness of the set $S$ defined in the original question follows from [Theorem 3.11 of Sambucini (1999)](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.36.3148&rep=rep1&type=pdf). However, it is a bit trickier to verify all the hypotheses: "total measurability of $F$", etc.

> **Possible issue.** *Something which appears weird is that **Method 2** seems to require convexity of $A$ while **Method 1** doesn't.*

Comment: Maharam's decomposition you mention holds only if the measure space is separable. Otherwise an uncountable number of copies of intervals is involved, though I do not know the details by heart. (AFAIK, only this non-separable version is due to D. Maharam; the separable version had been known long before.)

Comment: If you assume that $A$ is convex (and compact), it suffices to apply the earlier mentioned theorem: The set of measurable selections of an integrably bounded measurable multivalued function with compact convex values is weakly compact in $L_1$, Indeed if $a_n=\int f_n$ is a sequence in the image then the weak (sequential) compactness of $f_n$ implies that there is a subsequence with $\int f_{n_k}\to\int f$ weakly for some selection $f$. Because we are in the space $\mathbb R^n$, this implies strong convergence.

Comment: Maharam's theorem characterizes measure algebras, not measure spaces. This is a coarser classification. For example, the measure algebra of any probability space coincides with the measure algebra of its completion. Nevertheless, a suitable isomorphism theorem exists; one can find it in Royden's real analysis book.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your helpful comments. @MartinVäth Just to confirm: compactness of the selection $\mathfrak F := \{f \in L_1(X,P) \mid f(x) \in F(x) \text{ for }P-\text{a.e }x \in X\}$ (which appears to be known as Diestel's Theorem; see Theorem 3.1 of https://www.biz.uiowa.edu/faculty/nyannelis/publications/Integration%20of%20Banach-Valued%20Correspondences.pdf) implies compactness of $S$ since the mapping $I: f \mapsto \int_X f\,dP$ is continuous and $S=I(\mathfrak F)$, right ? Once again sorry for the naive questions.

Comment: @dohmatob: I am a bit surprised by the formulation of Theorem 3.1, because it is not defined what a convex correspondence is. I assume that it should be convex-valued and measurable in some previously defined sense, but there is no mentioning of any measurability hypothesis. But Diestel & Uhl have proved various theorems of this kind, maybe their monograph contains clearer formulations.

Comment: The mapping $I\colon f\mapsto\int_Xf\,dP$ is indeed continuous if image and preimage space are endowed with the weak topology. The essential argument needed to show this is that if $\varphi$ is a bounded functional in the image space then $\varphi\circ I$ is a bounded functional on $L_1$ (with the norm topology).
And the final step is of course to use the finite-dimensionality of $\mathbb R^n$ by using that weak and strong topology on the image space coincide.

Comment: @MartinVäth Thanks for the input. Do you have a standard reference for a result which would be in the flavor of Theorem 3.1 above (i.e on the weak compactness of $\mathfrak F$) ? Also a few comments back, what did you mean by "the earlier mentioned theorem" ? I ask because there are two many theorems being referenced at this point, and it's not clear which one you meant. Thanks in advance for the info.

Comment: No, I do not know a standard reference. Usually a good general reference in that area is the Springer lecture notes of Castaing & Valadier, but it may be too old for that (and is very hard to read, also because of the typesetting). As mentioned, perhaps the monograph of Diestel & Uhl might contain the result. By "the earlier mentioned theorem" I meant the theorem about weak compactness (what you called Diestel theorem) which you are looking a reference for. But if you are really only interested in the $\mathbb R^n$ case, I would check whether the proof in the Aumann paper is not enough.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Do you have a more exact reference in Roydens book or in general for the wlog assumption justified by Maharams theorem please? If I am not mistaken, in the fourth edition the words "Maharam" or "atom" do not appear.

Comment: @ViktorStein Royden only looks at separable measure algebras. The third edition has a subchapter named "Measure algebras."  Maharam's theorem is fairly deep. Complete proofs are in volume 3 of Fremlin's massive treatise or in "The Isometric Theory of Classical Banach Spaces" by Lacey.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Thanks for your quick response, I will look into it. Is a very special case of Maharam's theorem that if reasoning about a finite nonnegative (or probability) measure on say $\mathbb R^d$ I can without loss of generality assume that it is purely atomic or atomless?

Comment: Well, it will be a countable convex combination of atoms and something that looks like the unit interval with a uniform distribution. That is what separability buys.